# Openlitespeed 301 Moved Permanently problem

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, litespeed, openlitespeed

I have a new Openlitespeed server on Ubuntu, I have 2 domains pointing to the same IP,
I tried to make a multidomain server so that [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) would point to one website and [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com) to another.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob4qkNtlf04&ab_channel=TonyTeachesTech) tutorial.

Now when I go to domain1.com:80 it returns "CERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" and if I look at the network tab it shows:
[image]

and redirects me to http://domain1.com:8080/

If I go to domain2.com:80 it's the same but it redirects me to 8088.

Before that, I was hosting two testing pages on 8080 and 8088, but I changed all the settings and can't find what is causing the redirections... (both websites are wordpress)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this, something inside WordPress was redirecting.

I re-downloaded new WordPress and now it works.